# Can't connect to outside from the docker container managed by ECS on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have `ECS` which uses `EC2` and `EC2` has a `contianer`.

From `EC2 node` I can access the outside with this command.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-23-50 ~]$ curl google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Then I login container running on this node, `docker exec -it container-name /bin/bash`

```
 root@ip-172-31-24-234:/# curl google.com
```

I can't access(nothing appears).

So, I check the security group of `ECS Service`.

However all outbound connection is allowed

[image]

**Test**

on EC2 node I try to run another container (Becasue I wanted to test the container which is not managed by ECS service).

```
`docker run -it ubuntu`
```

then `install curl` and try `curl` in the this `ubuntu` containaer,I can connect to the outside from the container.

So the problem happens only in ECS managed container,

My task difinition is made by `CDK`, maybe this Network mode is related....??

```
const adminTaskDefinition = new ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(this, 'AdminTaskDefinition', {
  networkMode: ecs.NetworkMode.AWS_VPC,
})
```

Comment: Is your ECS task running in private subnet?

Comment: @AnkushJain No, EC2 node running on public subnets, and service also running on public subnets.

Comment: @whitebear maybe you could add some more details about the task definition of the service, cluster config etc.. in order to more efficiently debug it

Comment: Thank you for your comment!! I guess this might be related with network mode.. I will try again with another network mode.

Comment: As the service is running in public subnet and by default it wont have the public ip assigned to it. If there is no public ip assigned then it wont be able to access internet from internet gateway. Run the service in private subnet attached to nat gateway for security purpose. Or change the network mode to host or bridge.

Comment: Either do what Vikram said, or change the settings to assign a public IP address to the ECS task.

Comment: I change the mode to host mode, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps set your Network Mode = host in your task definition.

Comment: It is AWS_VPC, you can see it in CDK construct given in the question.

Comment: I changed network mode to `host`, then it works. When I set  `bridge`(it's default) mode it could access to the outside from the container, but I could't figure out how to container-container connection, but `host` mode worked perfect for me.